# Reading multiple excel files with pandas based on conditional, but pandas stops reading them if the first excel doesn't meet the condition

Tags: python, pandas

As the title says, I have this code that works for the most part, except when the first file it finds doesn't meet the condition, it doesn't read the rest of them. It should be filtering the column 'Value' when it finds a row that is >= 0.

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

def find_Excel():
    dfs = []
    path = 'c:/temp/*.xlsx'
    matches = [name for name in glob.glob(path)]

    set_list = list(set(matches))
    for filenames in set_list:
        df = pd.read_excel(filenames)
        parsed = df[df['Value'] >= 0]

        dfs.append(parsed)
    frame = pd.concat(dfs)
    print(len(frame))
```

I'm not entirely sure why this doesn't work, maybe I need to iterrows?  It seems to fail during reading the excel sheet, when the first one doesn't meet the 'parsed' criteria, it just stops

Comment: Do you have the exact error you're receiving? Could be a data type problem if the Value column is a string instead of a numeric.

Comment: Try using `try except ` in your code

Comment: I had a general pass exception but it still just stops reading it. And I tested it against the same sheet by adding a 1 to it and it reads it just fine.  Maybe I put it in the wrong place?

Answer (score 0):

I got it - sometimes it just takes someone else saying obvious things to get it, thanks to @Matt and @Tserenjamts.  The problem was that it was finding a corrupt file and breaking, so I just added a try except wrapped around pd.read_excel and it worked.  Dumby tax was my time.  Thanks